# Requiring a gem in rspec - What does it do?

Tags: ruby, rspec

When creating a gem, in the `spec_helper`, you are supposed to require the name of your gemfile, such as this:

```
require 'dogeify'
```

As explained here: [Building a gem from scratch](http://quickleft.com/blog/engineering-lunch-series-step-by-step-guide-to-building-your-first-ruby-gem)

My question is, what are you actually requiring? I don't see a file within the spec folder called dogeify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dogeify` mentioned in the project is the `lib/dogify.rb`. When running rspec as such

`bundle exec rake spec`, from the root of the gem, 
rspec will automatically add the lib directory to the load path and the `helper_spec` loads said file.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a `Gem`, gemfile will be save to your ruby environment, and use `require 'dogeify'`, then `require` function will find this file in ruby library folder or you application library, then load the `module` or `class` or `function` that defind by `dogeify` to your project. [Offical explanation at this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require)